# How To add Activity code To Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, feed

Hello Every one i will add this Activity in fragment

this fragment is for swipe menu 
and this activity is for feed reader
but the probleme is how to add this activity code in fragment

thanks all ;)

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
private static final String rssFeed = "http://softgriphost.esy.es/Android-Rss-software.xml";

List<Item> arrayOfList;
ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
        new MyTask().execute(rssFeed);
    } else {
        showToast("No Network Connection!!!");
    }

}

// My AsyncTask start...

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        arrayOfList = new NamesParser().getData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (null == arrayOfList || arrayOfList.size() == 0) {
            showToast("No data found from web!!!");
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        } else {

            // check data...
            /*
             * for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfList.size(); i++) { Item item =
             * arrayOfList.get(i); System.out.println(item.getId());
             * System.out.println(item.getTitle());
             * System.out.println(item.getDesc());
             * System.out.println(item.getPubdate());
             * System.out.println(item.getLink()); }
             */

            setAdapterToListview();

        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Item item = arrayOfList.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", item.getLink());
    intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra("desc", item.getDesc());
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void setAdapterToListview() {
    NewsRowAdapter objAdapter = new NewsRowAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.row, arrayOfList);
    listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);
}

public void showToast(String msg) {

}}
```

Fragment

```
public class PagesFragment extends Fragment {

public PagesFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);

    return rootView;
}}
```

thank you all :)

Comment: Here is the official google doc on implementing a navigation drawer in an android app. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you just asked but by looking at the code and reading what you have wrote, your logic in not that correct. You should have your swipe menu code in your activity, because it will be common between multiple parts of the application.

The way you implement the swipe menu is up to you, it can be inside the activity layout, or just a static fragment container inside the same activity.

Your feed reader should be a Fragment, because it will be reusable and used where you want. The idea behind fragment is that, they are 'parts' of screen that can be used anywhere in the activity, and should be self-sufficient, this meaning wherever you place that fragment, it should just work and do whatever he was designed to do, without any additional coding. Read the official android documentation about Activity and Fragments life cycle, it is worth reading, it explains almost everything you need to get started:
 http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: thank you @richard slond for this explain
i said 
the code of mainactivity
i will add to fragment 
please help me if you can ..  thank you  ;)

Comment: the best way to help you is providing references and places where you can learn. Read the documentation i gave you. If you want a more practical approach, i suggest you some nice videos i myself watched while i was learning android. Go to YouTube and look for 'slidenerd android', look for fragments usage, he does explain it very well. Good luck

Comment: start with this one good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GyGtCMoR_U&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo